# Are there any "smart" fuse boxes?

Tags: fuses, load

I'm not sure I know the proper term or how it is in other parts of the world, so I'll just explain in detail:

In my country every house has a "fuse box" - the electrical entry point to the house. This is where the electrical cables first enter the house and split off into the different electrical sockets. This box is also fitted with fuses that protect the cables from excessive loads by tripping/triggering and having to be replaced or switched back on.

Since we are (supposedly) in the 21st century I was wondering if they don't make some kind of "smart" fuse boxes - such that they would report how much energy each circuit is consuming and alert you if you are approaching the fuse tripping load.

I couldn't find anything similar online and, frankly, wouldn't be surprised if such a thing does not exist but I wanted to ask people who are more knowledgeable in the field.

Comment: Little bit googling led me to this: https://www.leviton.com/en/products/residential/load-centers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea; it looks like the answer is "Yes", and the right keywords are "smart distribution panel". Of course everything these days uses miniature circuit breakers (MCBs) rather than actual fuses.

[An example brochure.](https://download.schneider-electric.com/files?p_Doc_Ref=998-20135902_GMA-US&p_File_Ext=.PDF)

How good the associated software is, is another matter.

Comment: "Of course everything these days uses miniature circuit breakers (MCBs) rather than actual fuses."  HAH!  I have a relative who lives in a rental house that not only uses fuses, but screw-in glass ones.  In urban California, no less.

Comment: @TimWescott when I moved into my house (built around 1920) the whole place was "protected" by two 15 A glass fuses. Only took a year before I upgraded to a 400-A service. Which was a bit ridiculous because I never did build the big shop I thought I was going to.

Comment: One might also consider searching for a "smart consumer unit". A nice conceptual design here https://www.behance.net/gallery/30117881/Fuse-Smart-Consumer-Unit-Concept-Design